# Moving raster to different mapset GRASS GIS

Tags: raster, grass-gis

I have a raster DEM that I created in one mapset but I would like to copy it to another mapset for another purpose.

[image]

Is this possible within GRASS or can I just copy some files over in the filesystem to the FloodModels mapset folder on my hard drive?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with `g.copy` ([doc](http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass64/g.copy.html)) or `g.rename` ([doc](http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass64/g.rename.html)), something like:

```
g.copy rast="shire_dem@BushFire,shire_dem@FloodModels"
```

You can do this from the command line, but its a little more tricky generally, since the files are spread across a few directories.

Comment: I get the following error: `Illegal filename. Character <@> not allowed.

GRASS_INFO_WARNING(9384,1): <shire_dem@FloodModels> is an illegal file name
GRASS_INFO_END(9384,1)`

Comment: It's all good just needed to wrap it in quotes, so it became: rast="g.copy shire_dem@BushFire",shire_dem@FloodModels

Comment: Updated with the corrected information, thanks for the catch

Answer (score 5):

You need to indicate the dataformat, here raster. Additionally, don't define a target mapset since it always goes into the current mapset. So:

g.copy rast=shire_dem@BushFire,shire_dem