# GRASS module g.copy returns irrational outputs

Tags: grass-gis, python-2.7, windows-8

I took this as reference, [Moving raster to different mapset GRASS GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3140/moving-raster-to-different-mapset-grass-gis), and I use **pyscripter** to use GRASS module **g.copy** from outside,

```
import os
import sys

#set up GRASS environment variables
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['GISBASE'], 'etc', 'python'))
import grass.script as g
import grass.script.setup as gsetup
gisbase = os.environ['GISBASE']
gisdb = 'C:\Users\Heinz\Documents\grassdata'
location = 'newLocation'
mapset = 'watershed_analysis'
gsetup.init(gisbase, gisdb, location, mapset)

#copy raster data
g.run_command('g.copy', rast = 'hc@TC, hc')

#check result
print g.read_command('g.list', _type = 'rast')
```

The output is raster files in mapset PERMANENT, thus not what I want. (current mapset is watershed_analysis)

```
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
>>> 
----------------------------------------------

raster files available in mapset <PERMANENT>:
hc

----------------------------------------------
```

Seems I don't successfully copy the raster file to the mapset I want.

How to fix this problem？ I am using GRASS 6.4.3, python 2.7.6 under Windows 8.1 x64.

---

**Update#1**
@gene, I do the same thing in the python shell of the GRASS layer manager,

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>import grass.script as g
>>>g.run_command('g.copy', rast = 'acc@TC, acc@watershed_analysis')
0

>>>g.read_command('g.list', _type = 'rast')
----------------------------------------------

raster files available in mapset <PERMANENT>:
hc

----------------------------------------------

g.read_command('g.mlist', _type = 'rast')
hc
```

In the output above, I want to copy the file **acc** from mapset TC to current mapset watershed_analysis, but the output still tells me about another mapset. (g.list and g.mlist outputs the same except the later one wouldn't tell me the info of mapset.)

**And I go to check results in the file of this mapset, there are no new file copied to it.** Maybe there are problems in my script.

---

**Update#2**
If I tried the module in GRASS GUI, here's result,

[image]
[image]

No output but the error message,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\forms.py", line 655, in OnRun

self.goutput.RunCmd(cmd, onDone = self.OnDone)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\goutput.py", line 554, in RunCmd

task = GUI(show = None).ParseCommand(command)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\wxpython\gui_c
ore\forms.py", line 1871, in ParseCommand

blackList = _blackList)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python\grass\s
cript\task.py", line 470, in parse_interface

tree = etree.fromstring(get_interface_description(name))
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1300, in XML

parser.feed(text)
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1642, in feed

self._raiseerror(v)
  File
"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py",
line 1506, in _raiseerror

raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree
.
ParseError
:
unknown encoding: line 1, column 30
```

I don't know if I did something wrong in inputs.

Comment: strange, I have no problem on Mac OS X or Linux.

Comment: @gene some other modules like g.remove works fine, but some are returning strange outputs. I hope it's not problem relates to OS.

Comment: all the outputs are correct in my case. Try to execute your script in the Python shell of the GRASS Layer manager

Comment: @gene I have added the output from the built-in python shell.

Answer (score 2):

For the g.copy problem you should set two variables for the "from" and "to" maps then the command should be:

`g.run_command('g.copy', rast = (from, to))`

Have a look here how to format it correctly: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Python_Scripting_Library#Interface_to_copying_maps_.28g.copy.29

Regarding the g.mremove part, you need to add the '-f' flag (i.e. "force") to actually perform the remove. Without that flag g.mremove just outputs what it would have done

May I suggest that you separate two questions into two posts. Makes it easier for future generations to search and find relevant information.

Comment: thank you for your reply, and I will separate it into two posts, by the way, the link in your answer I can't open.

Comment: There is some issue with the whole "osgeo.org" servers since yesterday, so the grass wiki is down for a while. Try again in a day or so, I'm sure it will be up again.

Comment: (GRASS GIS server is back, system maintenance should be done.)